# Retry sending transactional emails in MailWizz

Tags: email, cron, transactions

Due to a server error, from yesterday to today I had 6,000 transactional emails in the queue (marked as "Unsent").
How can I resend them all today? Because cron is running normally but is only sending new emails. The ancients remain stationary (Unsent).
Have an SQL command or another cron command to run, or even an additional `script/plugin/extension` for that?

Comment: No is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by switching to PHPmailer:
Settings -> Common -> Default system mailer: PHPmailer